# Fetching all of a single customer’s orders on Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

Is there a way to get at all of a customer's orders on Shopify? For example:

```
o = ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(…).orders
```

Comment: (This question brought over from the [Shopify Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/shopify-api/H3gmCWxENyw))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment there isn't a way to filter orders by customer through that endpoint.

You will need to get all orders and filter them by their contents, which includes the customer id.

```
orders.select{ |o| o.customer.id == customer_id }
```

If this needs to be done quickly, then you may need to store the orders in your database, and keep them in sync with webhooks.  There is a **[Syncing with a Store](http://wiki.shopify.com/Syncing_with_a_Store)** page on the Shopify Wiki that explains how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Dylan.

If possible, can we add that to the API wish list? It would be great to be able to get Order records filtered by `customer_id`. For example, "show me the 10 most recent pending orders belonging to a customer".

Comment: The best place to leave feature requests is https://github.com/shopify/shopify_api until we’ve got all the API docs into a proper GitHub repo of their own.

Answer (score -2):

The customer's identity is based on their email address. So if you search the orders by the customer's email, you should be able to get all their orders:

```
@customer = ShopifyAPI::Customer.first
@orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, params: { email: @customer.email })
```

Comment: This doesn't find all the orders for that customer email, it just returns all the orders. The email param doesn't do anything and is ignored.